# How to add a mass action via xml in Magento 2?

Tags: grid, magento2-dev-beta, massaction

**Scenario:**
I have a custom CRUD module and I need to have a mass action in the admin grid that I can use to mass update the status for example.
The module uses the new xml grid system from Magento 2 (see as example `app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_grid_block.xml`).

**Issue:**
I can add any mass action item that does not require an additional input.

```
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction" name="[module].[entity].grid.massaction" as="grid.massaction">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="massaction_id_field" xsi:type="string">[entity]_id</argument>
                    <argument name="form_field_name" xsi:type="string">[entity]_ids</argument>
                    <argument name="use_select_all" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="delete" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">[module_route]/[entity]/massDelete</item>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete the items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

I cannot add a mass action item that requires an additional select. In the example above, I need a select with 2 statuses `enabled` & `disabled`.

In Magento 1 this was possible via `_prepareMassaction` method in the grid block:

```
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
        'status',
        array(
            'label'      => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Change status'),
            'url'        => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
            'additional' => array( //this allows an additional select.
                'status' => array(
                    'name'   => 'status',
                    'type'   => 'select',
                    'class'  => 'required-entry',
                    'label'  => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Status'),
                    'values' => array(
                        '1' => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Enabled'),
                        '0' => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Disabled'),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Magento 1 result:

[image: mass action]

**Question:**
How can I get the same result in Magento 2 (0.74.0-beta1) via xml grid definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands I don't think it's possible (without modifiying the behaviour of the addItem method.) it looks to me like the XML ability is used in `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction\AbstractMassaction` which `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction\Extended` doesn't extend but only Extended has the ability to add multiple action blocks.

However only Massaction\Extended has the correct template and to below code in the addItem method which adds the additional block.

```
if ($this->_items[$itemId]->getAdditional()) {
        $this->_items[$itemId]->setAdditionalActionBlock($this->_items[$itemId]->getAdditional());
        $this->_items[$itemId]->unsAdditional();
    }
```

I managed to make it work but it required using a plugin and updating the template via XML, you can then use XML like below:

```
 <action method="setTemplate">
                            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend::widget/grid/massaction_extended.phtml</argument>
                        </action>
```

.

```
<item name="cancel_order" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cancel</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sales/order/massCancel</item>
                                <item name="additional" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="visibility" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                                        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">required-entry</item>
                                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                                        <item name="values" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">Enabled</item>
                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">Disabled</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
```

The Preference (rewrite) I created for \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TheExtensionLab_Massaction" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Config"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction">
        <plugin name="theextensionlab-massaction-add-additional" type="TheExtensionLab\Massaction\Model\Widget\Grid\Massaction\Plugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**TheExtensionLab\Massaction\Model\Widget\Grid\Massaction\Plugin.php**

```
<?php
    namespace TheExtensionLab\Massaction\Model\Widget\Grid\Massaction;

    class Plugin extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction
    {

        public function aroundAddItem($subject,$proceed,$itemId,$item){

            $returnValue = $proceed($itemId,$item);

            $returnValue->_items[$itemId] = $returnValue->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction\Item'
            )->setData(
                $item
            )->setMassaction(
                $returnValue
            )->setId(
                $itemId
            );

            if ($returnValue->_items[$itemId]->getAdditional()) {
                $returnValue->_items[$itemId]->setAdditionalActionBlock($returnValue->_items[$itemId]->getAdditional());
                $returnValue->_items[$itemId]->unsAdditional();
            }

            return $returnValue;
        }

    }
```

*Note: I'm not sure about extending the Plugin with the Massaction class just to be able to update the private variables but I figure thats better that rewriting/using preferences to edit just the one function.*

Comment: This seams to work. Just one comment. Instead of using the `around` plugin, I think an `after` plugin would be safer. The first line of your plugin is `$proceed($itemId,$item)` so everything in your code is executed after the original method. `around` plugins are dangerous. But those are just details.  I dug deeper based on your suggestions and indeed there is not way (I didn't find one) to add complex mass actions without plugins or preferences. This needs to be changed.  Thank you for everything.

Comment: Hi @marius, yeah I thought the same thing but was unable to get the params in the After Plugin method and without them this gets more complicated I think because we don't then have the additional data to hand. Might ask M2 to add those in.

Comment: I see now. I tested with your approach and it was enough for me. I just thought it might work with `after` plugin, but didn't test. apparently I was wrong. Anyway. I will open a ticked on M2, because we should be able to add complex mass actions via xml directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With block Grid is Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid You can define layout xml below:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction" name="permission.user.grid.massaction" as="grid.massaction">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="massaction_id_field" xsi:type="string">user_id</argument>
                <argument name="form_field_name" xsi:type="string">user_id</argument>
                <argument name="use_select_all" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="delete" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Users</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massDelete</item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure?</item>
                        <item name="block_name" xsi:type="string">grid.massaction.delete.additional</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction\Additional"
                   name="permission.user.grid.massaction.delete.additional" as="grid.massaction.delete.additional">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="fields" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="current_password" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Password</item>
                            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">current_password</item>
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">password</item>
                            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
```

This is my result when add mass action delete on Users grid with layout grid
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **The below are examples to add mass action in Magento's search term grid**

**app/code/VendorName/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout**

**search_term_grid_block.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.catalog.search.grid.massaction">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_updated" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Updated</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">routeName/controllerName/MassAction</item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to update?</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendorName/Modulename/Controller/Adminhtml/Term**

**MassAction.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Term;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Search\Controller\Adminhtml\Term as TermController;

class MassDateUpdate extends TermController implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $searchData  = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        print_r($searchData);
        exit();
    }

}
```

**Note: You need to create your custom route or use the default existing route name.**

**The reference file for Massaction:**

```
vendor/magento/module-search/Controller/Adminhtml/Term/MassDelete.php
```

**[Click here to use the default existing route name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232416/82670)**