# Magento 2 How to over write route FrontName of a module?

Tags: magento2, module, router, di.xml

I'm trying to extend Magento 2 default module Magente_Contact, but I can't change the frontName, I tried to put in the di.xml, but nothing happens.

```
<config>
    <router id="standart">
        <route id="contact" frontName="contato">
            <module name="[VENDOR]_Contact" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Contact\etc\frontend\routes" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\etc\front\routes" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a tricky way,you can change the contact us `Magento_Contact` module's frontend Name

First,  **etc/module.xml** of your module's make `Magento_Contact`  as a depended module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And then changes frontend name from `routes.xm`l at `etc/frontend/`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="contact" frontName="contato">
            <module name="Magento_Contact" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**di.xml is not required**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't work, error: `Front controller reached 100 router match iterations`. And if I try to access `{site_url}/contact`, It still works. I changed Magente_Contact to Magento_Contact.  Isn't necessary a di.xml file?

Comment: It looks like a can't use route id as contact `<route id="contact" frontName="contato">` , but if I change it can't find the right layout file.

Comment: di.xml is  not requied

Comment: aha. od good bad mistake `changed Magente_Contact to Magento_Contact.`.Updated answer

Comment: It still doesn't work, with Magento_Contact. Keep happening `Front controller reached 100 router match iterations` if I use router id as "contact".

Answer (score 0):

So, I couldn't rewrite the route frontName. What i did to work around it, was create a new frontName route with a new Controller and rewrite like this:

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class Index extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Index
{
    protected $_http;

    protected $resultFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, ConfigInterface $contactsConfig, ResultFactory $resultFactory, Http $http)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $contactsConfig);
        $this->_http = $http;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_http->setRouteName('contact');
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__("Contato"));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Not the best solution, but worked.